# How to sort data in a table using pl sql block

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have already given ranks in rank_id column of top_books and i want to update the same table according to count_issue attribute while keeping the rank_id as they are. Can this be done somehow?

```
DECLARE
  v_row NUMBER;
  CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT COUNT(transaction_id) counter, book_id 
    FROM transaction_master 
    GROUP BY book_id;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN cur LOOP
    v_row:=cur%ROWCOUNT;
    UPDATE top_books 
    SET book_id = rec.book_id, count_issue = rec.counter 
    WHERE rank_id = v_row;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

How can i sort the above updated data in table top_books within this code block according to 'COUNT_ISSUE' attribute

Comment: why do you want to sort it?

Comment: Why do you use a slow-by-slow approach and update the rows in a loop? This can be done with a single statement. I also think your `where` condition is wrong. Shouldn't that be `where booki_id = rec.book_id`? `v_row:=cur%ROWCOUNT;` is not changing in the loop, so you are updating the same row over and over again.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why don't you think `v_row:=cur%rowcount;` wouldn't change? `declare v_cnt number; cursor cur is select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 100; begin for rec in cur loop v_cnt := cur%rowcount; dbms_output.put_line (v_cnt); end loop; end;` is enough to prove that it does. It's a convoluted way of achieving what the OP wants though, IMHO!

Comment: @Boneist: a right, I somehow thought that would return the total count of the cursor. But I still don't understand why the where clause doesn't include the book_id...

Comment: @Boneist  @ a_horse_with_no_name where clause does not include book_id because i have already given rank_id and i want to update the table according to rank_id where book_id with highest count_issue should be at top ie rank_id 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this you can do it for update also but approach bit confusing just change your cursor;

```
DECLARE
  v_row NUMBER;
 CURSOR cur IS
    select * from (SELECT COUNT(transaction_id) counter, book_id 
    FROM transaction_master 
    GROUP BY book_id) order by counter desc;

BEGIN
  -- truncate table
  execute immediate 'truncate table top_books';
  --insert fresh data
  FOR rec IN cur LOOP
    v_row := cur%rowcount;
   insert into top_books (rank_id,book_id,ciybt_issue) values(v_row,rec.book_id,rec.counter);
  END LOOP;
  commit;
END;
```

Comment: you can try bulk insert as well.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do this using a cursor for loop; instead, I'd do it in a single MERGE statement:

```
merge into top_books tgt
using (select row_number() over (order by cnt desc, book_id) rn,
              book_id,
              cnt
       from   (select   book_id,
                        count(transaction_id) cnt
               from     transaction_master
               group by book_id)) src
  on (tgt.rank_id = src.rn)
when matched then
  update set tgt.book_id = src.book_id,
             tgt.count_issue = src.cnt;
```

It will be much faster than your row-by-row (aka slow-by-slow) approach.

N.B. I've used the `row_number` analytic function rather than `rank` or `dense_rank` to determine the order of books sold since if two books happened to have the same count, then the update would fail. You should amend the extra ordering (here, I used book_id to differentiate which book would come first) to achieve the results you're after.

Answer (score 1):

The data is not sorted in itself within the top_books table. That would be against the SQL paradigm. You sort the data when you query the table, for instance:

```
SELECT book_id, count_issue
FROM top_books
ORDER BY count_issue DESC
```

If you want to use this within PL/SQL, you can define a cursor with this query which will give you the records one at a time in sorted order.

Comment: I have already given ranks in rank_id column of top_books and i want to update the same table according to count_issue attribute while keeping the rank_id as they are.  Can this be done somehow?

Comment: @msj003 you should include that paragraph in your question. It's not clear what you're trying to do in it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for help,
I found answer to this by making changes to my cursor as

```
CURSOR cur IS
SELECT COUNT(transaction_id) counter, book_id 
FROM transaction_master 
GROUP BY book_id ORDER BY counter desc;
```

Comment: It's possible to empty a bath by using a jug. But why would you want to, when you could simply pull up the bathplug? In other words: why do you want to continue with this row-by-row approach when there's a set-based way of doing it in a single sql statement?

Comment: i have to do all this through an Oracle forms Trigger and i wanted to sort the updated table... i still have issues with above code looking for a better answer